# Android difference beetween System.setProperty and getSharedPreferences?

Tags: android

What is the best way, to save a widget data?

what is the differences beetween setProperty and sharedPreferences, what is the best way to save appwidget datas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). System.setProperty()

- may not work at all
- will not survive phone restart

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem.
After I read the source between property and sharedPreferences,I think sharedPreferences is more advanced more property, they both use map to store data and can save to file, load form file.
sharedPreferences is better encapsulated and auto save to xml file. they are both thread safe.
In Android, i recommend you to use sharedPreferences.